# How to use Nextjs middleware to redirect users to sub-domain based on IP

Tags: javascript, next.js, middleware

I'm trying to figure out how to properly use NextJs's middleware to route users from a specific country to another web domain and I couldn't get it to work properly. Below is my setup:

Main domain:  https://www.example.com
sub-domain:   https://ca.example.com

src/middleware.js

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export function middleware(req) {
  const { nextUrl: geo } = req;
  const country = geo.country;
  if (country === "CA") {
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL(`https://ca.example.com`));
  }
}
```

The above does not work and I have a feeling that I might have misunderstood how middleware works in my use case. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried to console log `country` constant?

Comment: @Hostek I did, local dev returns "undefined", I haven't tried uploading it to a server tho

Comment: I think middleware.js should be in the `pages` directory;

Comment: And req.nextUrl does not have country property. Maybe you are looking for geo.locale?

Comment: @Hostek I tried moving middleware to the pages directory, not seem to work :/, I think it has to do with how my code is written.

Comment: @Hostek and I believe middleware needs to be put into the src folder and next to the "pages" folder according to the doc "https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/middleware-upgrade-guide"

Comment: By doing `const { nextUrl: geo } = req;` you're simply renaming `nextUrl` to `geo`, you're not actually accessing `req.geo`. That's why `geo.country` wouldn't work. You have to access it with `const { geo } = req;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out myself. I've simplified the code and it works now

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export function middleware(req) {
  const country = req.geo.country;
  if (country === "CA") {
    return NextResponse.redirect("https://ca.example.com");
  } else {
    return;
  }
}
```

Comment: It did not work, because you were accesing `req.nextUrl.country` before.